# css working in IE but not in firefox?

Tags: css

background: url(../images/corner_tr.gif) no-repeat top right;

working in IE but not working in firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
background: url(../images/corner_tr.gif) no-repeat top right;
width:image width here. /* ff needs to be told explicitly */
height: image height here. /* ff needs to be told explicitly */
```

Answer (score 2):

hey check out this.......

http://noroots.blogspot.com/2006/05/css-works-in-ie-but-not-firefox.html

Answer (score 1):

```
background: url(../images/corner_tr.gif) no-repeat right center;
```

you interchange the positions